# Django datetime.date.min and Mysql DATE minimum value is different

Tags: python, mysql, django, date

### Actual Question

How can i deal with different minimum date in Django `DateField` and Mysql `DATE` type. What can be done to deal with the issue?

### TL:DR

[`datetime.date.min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.date.minhttps://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.date.max) has lower value than minimum supported in Mysql for `DATE` type. Saving `datetime.date.min` to Mysql is possible but it is not guaranteed to work.

### Context

I'm working with Django (v1.11) model:

```
class MyModel(model.Model):
    begin_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Currently the fields with `NULL` value designate the lower and higher date range limits respectively.
Example:

Date range from beginning of time to today will be:

```
mymodel.begin_date = None
mymodel.end_date = datetime.date(2019, 11, 20)
mymodel.save()
```

The usage of `None`/`NULL` creates a need to convert it to [`datetime.date.min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.date.minhttps://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.date.max)/[`datetime.date.max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.date.max) on any sorting operations etc. Simply put: its inconvenient and adds unnecessary complexity.

My though was to do necessary migrations and start putting `datetime.date.min`/`datetime.date.max` instead of `None`/`NULL'

But there is a problem:

**Mysql has different min/max date range**

According to the [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html):

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part.
>   MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The
>   supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.

According to python docs:

> The smallest year number allowed in a date or datetime object. MINYEAR is 1.
>
> The largest year number allowed in a date or datetime object. MAXYEAR is 9999.
>
> The earliest representable date, date(MINYEAR, 1, 1).
>
> The latest representable date, date(MAXYEAR, 12, 31).

It turns out that in Django you can still use `datetime.date.min` and it will be saved to the database. **But it is not guranteed to work.**

Because of:

> For the DATE and DATETIME range descriptions, “supported” means that although earlier values might work, there is no guarantee.

### My idea

I'm thinking about doing all necessary migrations, clean the code from `None` convertions and just use [`Field.default`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#default). Set it to `default=datetime(1000, 1, 1)` (minimum mysql supported date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your idea will work fine.

Note that it's database-specific, though. The more ungainly approach of using `None` does have the virtue of working across databases.

Also note that apparently MySQL let's you store dates below that ostensible minimum value. Therefore, there could be dates in the database that will not be caught by your filter. So be sure to validate dates before you store them to make sure they are at or above the minimum.